# book that I could make an indie game

Tags: books

What kind of book I read, that should do a full indie game?

Comment: This question needs some more details. At least provide the platform you would like to develop for and what topics the book should cover. Programming? Design? Marketing?

Comment: for Windows PC with c++, a full indie game from start to finish

Comment: In that case, maybe have a look at this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3637/what-is-a-good-book-to-start-programming-a-2d-c-game

Comment: "How do I make a game" is too broad a topic, even if you're asking for links to books.  There are also lots of "getting started" and "book recommendation" type questions already here.

Answer (score 1):

For game design I can recommend [The Art of Game Design: A book of lenses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123694965).

Comment: That is an awesome book and I highly recommend it to all game designers, but it's no end-to-end technical text.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little on what you are looking for a game.

You could do some Flash Games with little scripting but you have to learn the Flash scripting itself.
If you can program C/C++/C#/Java you can find [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11948/game-programming-books-that-dont-teach-programming) some books which could be very interesting.

So, what is it what you can and what is it what you want to create?

Comment: for a beginning a simple physics game and later a full indie game with c++ for Windows PC. I mean the game design is also. In order to fully complete an indie game.

Comment: The largest part of my question is: I am thinking whether I should join the team to create a game?