# Language agnostic game programming books

Tags: software-engineering, game-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Game programming books that don't teach programming?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11948/game-programming-books-that-dont-teach-programming)
>   [Must read game development books](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/must-read-game-development-books)

Does anyone know any good language independent game programming books?

I don't currently know anything about game programming or practices - any good books on stuff like: scene-graphs, handling sprites, layers, collision detection, effects, events?

I'm a college student without the time to learn a new language so the concepts need to be language-agnostic enough they can fit into the languages I know: Javascript, Python, Scheme/Lisp and some light Vala (I'm considering using HTML5 or PyGame). I would use C# books but my OS is Linux and I don't know about the whole mono thing when most C# books use XNA.

Also I know that game programming is an extension of general programming, but I think I've got that down. Like is there a cookbook of some sort?